# Commits UI returns replacements.flatMap error

Tags: scmmanager

Browsing commits in the web UI at `/scm/repo/namspace/repo_name/code/branch/default/changesets` returns `replacements.flatMap` is not a function, see image:
[SCM error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0XQC.png)

I traced this to `scm-ui\ui-components\src\repos\changesets\ChangesetDescription.tsx` in line 46.

My deployment is in a docker container but I was able to verify the issue on a physical deployment of the application as well. Am I missing a dependency?

edit: The deployed version of `scm-manager` is 2.3.0 in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved by updating my browser to a newer version.

Comment: Hi, Paul i'm one of the maintainers of SCM-Manager. Could you please tell us which browser do you use and which version the old one was?

Comment: Sure, I was using a version of Google Chrome that was released in 2018 at the time of the error, I believe it was version 47. I verified the application works fine with Chrome 84.0.4147.105 and Firefox 68 esr.